# import ssl error on fresh install: 'PROTOCOL_TLS' is not defined

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ssl, anaconda

On a fresh 64-bit install of Anconda2 (4.3.1) with Python 2 (2.7.13) on Windows 10, I get the following error:

```
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\username_redacted\Anaconda2\lib\ssl.py", line 133, in <module>
  PROTOCOL_SSLv23 = PROTOCOL_TLS
NameError: name 'PROTOCOL_TLS' is not defined
```

I realise there are a few postings about SSL problems with Python in Anaconda that could be related: I've already tried running things like `conda update openssl`, I don't have `certifi` installed, and `pip install ssl` doesn't work (since ssl is bundled with python now, I guess).

Does anyone have any advice? I'm trying to get BioPython to work, in case there's some sort of BioPython-specific fix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed on a fresh box and this isn't an issue in the latest version (as of April 2018) that I can see.